# GPU training speed is slower / same as my CPU

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I know this probably was posted a lot of times, I have also tried out some of the solutions as well but I am rather new to these and I am not too sure where it might have gone wrong.
To put short my problem, my CPU takes about 120 min for torch training on 20k x 20 dataset with 4 layers while GPU also takes 130min on the same training.

I have followed the steps as listed in
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html 1

and also used

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

for downloading the pytorch. At first I downloaded 12.3 version from nvidia instead, and now I have deleted (both with system add/remove and conda uninstall cuda) and re-downloaded to 12.1 version.But I am not too sure why I get the below values when I print them (why 12.3 instead of 12.1?) I can verify my torch.cuda.is_available() returns true.

```
print(‘__Python VERSION:’, sys.version)
print(‘__pyTorch VERSION:’, torch.version)
print(‘__CUDA VERSION’, )

__Python VERSION: 3.11.8 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Feb 26 2024, 21:34:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
__pyTorch VERSION: 2.2.1
__CUDA VERSION
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov_22_10:30:42_Pacific_Standard_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.107
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33567101_0
```

I have also moved the data to cuda with code example below

```
X_train_tensor_gpu = X_train_tensor.to(‘cuda’)
model = Net()
model.to(‘cuda’)
```

nvidia-smi returns as below

```
Wed Mar 6 14:59:19 2024
±----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 551.61 Driver Version: 551.61 CUDA Version: 12.4 |
|-----------------------------------------±-----------------------±---------------------+
| GPU Name TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap | Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
| | | MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
| 0 NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 … WDDM | 00000000:01:00.0 On | N/A |
| 0% 40C P8 20W / 285W | 1746MiB / 16376MiB | 6% Default |
| | | N/A |
±----------------------------------------±-----------------------±---------------------+
```

Not too sure if this is how you monitor GPU usage but running the process & checking it in task manager - performance shows my GPU utilisation goes up to 94% so I do think it should be using my GPU plus it’s 4070 Ti Super so I dont see why it would be slower than my CPU.

Anyone can help…? not too sure what other info is needed.

Comment: how much RAM do you have?

Comment: GPU Vram? 16GB.
System RAM 32GB. (2x 16)

Comment: I had a similar situation before where CPU was quicker than GPU because the CPU was larger. Without knowing more, I would say the problem might be there. How does the performance look like when you reduce the size of your training dataset?

Comment: I have tried with reducing the number of epochs and number of features but regardless, it was still almost same/ slightly slower to train. 
I thought benefit of having GPU acceleration is for the large size of dataset..?

Comment: I can recommend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63833261/16815358

Comment: Thank you very much my good sir but the answer also kinda states that the larger the amount of computation, usually GPU performs better. Since my dataset is not small (about 90MB of data), I still expect it to perform better haha. I am just a little unsure if the CUDA versions have any impact on the compatibility with the torch binding with 12.1 CUDA. not sure why uninstalling and installing still give me cuda version to be 12.3 instead of 12.1.